# Path of SilverStripe folders created in LeftandMain

Tags: silverstripe

I created a new folder 'new' inside the SilverStripe CMS GUI/LeftandMain.  What is the path to 'new' so I can access the folder 'new' in my templates/.ss files?

Comment: What do you mean you created a folder? Do you mean in the [Files tab of the CMS](https://userhelp.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/creating_pages_and_content/creating_and_editing_content/working_with_images_and_documents/)?

Comment: @3dgoo yes files tab of the CMS, it's a folder of images I wanted to access in my templates using img tag.

Comment: Files and folders added to the Files tab live in the `assets` directory in the file system.

Comment: inside assets are user created folders in _combinedfiles folder because I don't see the 'new' folder. I uploaded a file but it's not even there.

Comment: Folders created in the files tab will be in the assets directory. If you do not see them there it is for a different reason. Perhaps user error.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image in your template? There are better ways to display cms controlled images in templates

Comment: @3dgoo you're correct there are in assets, it's just seem they are hidden when ls/dir. what I'm trying to do is display images stored in assets by simply referencing them in an img tag in my templates.

Comment: When the folder or file is not on the server you might check if the server has all permissions to assets. What's the user who created / uploaded assets? what user user is running the webserver...?

Comment: the default user (admin / root) created everything, I'm able to access but can not ls them, just wondering.